# How to achieve Hibernate composite key relation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have clases which look something like this.  I want to associate user with locality.  Where there is a OneToMany relation between City-Locality.  How to achieve this

```
public class User {

    private Long userId;    
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
}

@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String cityName;
    private String pinCode;
}

@Entity
public class Locality { 
    private Long Id;
    private String localityName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model lacks clarity a bit - there is no information about either city or locality in User entity. However, if you would add locality id field to user entity, solution will look like below:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long userId;

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCALITY_ID")
    private Locality locality;

    //setters/getters omitted
}


@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String cityName;
    private String pinCode;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCALITY_ID") // join column is in table for LOCALITY
    private Set<Locality> localities;

    //setters/getters omitted
}
```